# Should add and use image inside src folder or public folder?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Sorry if my question has already existed.

I know that we can add and use image in both public folder and inside src folder. so What is better way to use?

Answer (score 1):

Each of us will have different opinions on how the files should be placed within the app. But I would prefer keeping the images inside the `src` folder of the app.

You can refer to an article here - https://medium.com/@Charles_Stover/optimal-file-structure-for-react-applications-f3e35ad0a145 explaining about the folder structure.

Comment: And about app's performance? Have any difference between two ways above?